# Word 2010 - Changing numbers into text

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to change `$94,000` to display as `ninety-four thousand and 00/100`. I have used the fields and changed to number text but it incorrectly changes the amount.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how the resulting amount is incorrect?

Answer (score 7):

### To convert a number value into words...

1. **Select** the number.

   [image: select]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to embed the selected text in a field.

   [image: embed]
3. Edit the field to match the following format:

   ```
   {=VALUE \* DollarText}
   ```

   [image: dollar text]
4. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update the field!

   [image: result]