# MS Word - Text based on formula

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I work in finance, and often have to type things like "£5,023 (Five Thousand And Twenty Three Pounds)" into Word documents.

I have an Excel spreadsheet where I can paste the number 5023 and copy the words from the results cell. But this isn't useful for my less tech-savvy team members.

I would like to be able to select the digits (5023), press a macro button, and have the text appear following the number. Ideally linked to the number, so that it auto-updates when the number is changed; but if the macro just creates static text, that's a big improvement from colleagues spending too long mistyping the text!

So basically, a macro where the input is the selected text, and the output is the result of a calculation based on that text, pasted into the document.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word 2010 - Changing numbers into text](https://superuser.com/questions/424572/word-2010-changing-numbers-into-text)

Comment: @cosmogoblin If the below answer solved your questions, please help out the community and mark it as solved. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching for is a `cardtext` field.

## How To Spell Out Numbers

1. Press `CTRL`+`F9` to insert a field. This will insert the {} brackets for a field. Do not insert these brackets manually or it will not work.
2. In that field enter `=` + the number you want spelled out + `\*cardtext`. Example: `{=5023\*cardtext}`
3. Right-click on the field and select "Update field"
4. If you later on want to edit the field, right click on it and select "Toggle field codes". Then change finish your edits and continue with step 3. again.

Word will now show: `five thousand twenty-three`.
Note, that this only works for numbers up to 999,999. Everything above is not possible in Word.

## How To Format The Spelled Out Numbers

- To capitalize each word, use the formatting code `\*caps` in your field like this: `{=5023\*cardtext \*caps}` to receive the output `Five Thousand Twenty-Three`
- To capitalize each character, use the formatting code  `\*upper` in your field like this: `{=5023\*cardtext \*upper}` to receive the output `FIVE THOUSAND TWENTY-THREE`

## How To Link The Field To A Number In Your Document

1. (see steps 1-3 above)
2. Highlight your original number `5023` (in the text, not in the field), go to Insert > Bookmark, and create a new bookmark which references this number. Let's say you used the bookmark name `value`.
3. To now reference this bookmark from inside a field, simply change the field code from `{=5023\*cardtext}` to `{={REF value \h}\*cardtext}`. Remember to not use standard {} brackets. You always need to created them with `CTRL`+`F9`

IMPORTANT: Whenever you change bookmark contents, be very careful how you do that. When you go to `Options` > `Advanced` and activate the box `Show bookmarks` in the `Show document content section`, then you will see [] brackets around your created bookmarks. So your number will actually look like this: `[5023]`. When you now start changing that number by clicking at the end of it and then deleting the last digit `3`, you will see that you shortened the bookmark to `[502]`. If you now add a number at the end, it won't be contained in the bookmark. So, adding a `2` for example will lead to `[502]2` where the added 2 is outside of the bookmark. To solve this, always change from within the bookmark. When you have the number `[5023]`, click right between number `2` and number `3`, add your number `2` > `[50223]` and then delete the number `3` > `[5022]`. Like this you made sure that all the numbers are still within the bookmark.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you!

I don't have access to MS Word right now (weekend) but I'll give it a go next week.

Cheers!

Comment: @cosmogoblin sounds good. In case everything worked that way, please make sure to mark this answer as the solution.